# Run Java 17 on Yocto OS

Tags: java, linux, docker, yocto

My colleagues and I are trying to build a Yocto OS Image.
Our application consists of several Micro-Services written with Java 17 and they require to run on an embedded device ([phyCORE i.MX 8M Plus Setup Guide](https://www.phytec.de/cdocuments/?doc=LAC7Ig)). On another System we would run them within Docker containers and deploy them this way but since none of us have ever worked on a Yocto build before, we are kinda stuck getting things to work and finding the layers we have to add to the Yocto build.

We did get the [meta-java layer](https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors-Knowledge-Base/How-to-add-openjdk-to-Yocto-Layers/ta-p/1128283) to install but that is only based on openjdk-8.

The following files are the current build configuration

**local.conf**

```
MACHINE ?= "phyboard-pollux-imx8mp-3"

DISTRO ?= "ampliphy-vendor"

########################
# global configuration #
########################

# That are the default values of bitbake.  Adapt these to your workspace and
# host preferences.
#DL_DIR = "${TOPDIR}/downloads"
#SSTATE_DIR = "${TOPDIR}/sstate-cache"

# License Handling
#  - Uncomment for i.MX6 proprietary GPU libraries
#LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST += "license-nxp_v14-june-2016_imx-gpu-viv"
#  - Uncomment for Freescale i.MX6 VPU firmware blobs
#LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST += "license-freescale_v12-march-2016_firmware-imx"

# build artifacts are deployed here
DEPLOY_DIR = "${TOPDIR}/deploy"

# enable bitbakes git shallow functionality: this reduces download volume
# from 7.3G to 1.6 G as of sumo. If you need the git history of a project,
# you can run a "git remote update" in the tmp dir, as the remotes are
# correctly specified
BB_GIT_SHALLOW = "1"

# Select configuration UI for linux and barebox recipe. The openembedded
# default is 'menuconfig', 'nconfig' has more features.
# busybox only supports menuconfig
#KCONFIG_CONFIG_COMMAND = "menuconfig"
KCONFIG_CONFIG_COMMAND = "nconfig"
KCONFIG_CONFIG_COMMAND_pn-busybox = "menuconfig"

# SDK will be build for that cpu
#SDKMACHINE ?= "x86_64"

# bitbake disk monitor setup
BB_DISKMON_DIRS ??= "\
    STOPTASKS,${TMPDIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${DL_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${SSTATE_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,/tmp,100M,100K \
    ABORT,${TMPDIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${DL_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${SSTATE_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,/tmp,10M,1K"

#######################
# Image configuration #
#######################

# The following line disables the autostart of the phytec-qtdemo by
# default, but you can start the demo anytime using
#  $ systemctl start phytec-qtdemo.service
#SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE_pn-phytec-qtdemo = "disable"

# You can disable and enable FSTYPES as you wish. e.g. 'ext4'.
# This variable is ordering dependend.
#IMAGE_FSTYPES = "tar.gz wic ubifs emmc"

# To change the variable for any imx8 machine:
#IMAGE_FSTYPES_mx8 = "tar.gz wic ubifs emmc"

# Turn on debugging options of the kernel
#DEBUG_BUILD_pn-linux-mainline = "1"
# Turn on debugging options of the imx kernel
#DEBUG_BUILD_pn-linux-imx = "1"
# Turn on debugging options of the barebox
#DEBUG_BUILD_pn-barebox = "1"

# Include kernel sources in SDK
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " kernel-devsrc"

# The default package class of the distro ampliphy is 'package_ipk'. The first
# value is used as the package manager to build the image and sdk. To build
# also tar packages use
#PACKAGE_CLASSES = "package_ipk package_tar"

# Variable IMAGE_ROOTFS_EXTRA_SPACE from poky/meta/conf/documentation.conf:
#   Defines additional free disk space created in the image in Kbytes. By
#   default, this variable is set to '0'.
# This example line adds an additional 512 MiB of free space to the root
# filesystem:
#IMAGE_ROOTFS_EXTRA_SPACE = "524288"

# See http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-features-image
#    Through these variables, you can add several different predefined
#    packages such as development utilities or packages with debug information
#    needed to investigate application problems or profile applications
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES = ""
# - "Makes an image suitable for development (e.g. allows root logins without
#    passwords and enables post-installation logging)"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += "debug-tweaks"
# - "Installs debug symbol packages for all packages installed in a given
#    image."
#EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += "dbg-pkgs"
# - "Installs debugging tools such as strace and gdb."
#EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += "tools-debug"

######################
# rauc configuration #
######################

# certificate location for signing bundles
#CERT_PATH = "${TOPDIR}/../sources/meta-ampliphy/openssl-ca"

####################
# QT configuration #
####################

# We disable qt widgets per default to save about 10 MB of storage. If
# you need qt widget support, you can enable it with this line
#DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " qtwidgets"

CONF_VERSION = "1"

# Uncomment to accept NXP EULA (needed, if any NXP / freescale layer is used)
# EULA can then be found under ../sources/meta-freescale/EULA
ACCEPT_FSL_EULA = "1"

# A TISDK BSP requires per default an external toolchain
# Provide a default path that is compatible to our TISDK docker image
TOOLCHAIN_BASE ?= "/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs"

############################################
# Addition of openjdk-8 and minicom to the default build
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/java-initial-native = "cacao-initial-native"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/java-native = "jamvm-native"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/javac-native = "ecj-bootstrap-native"

IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " minicom openjdk-8"
############################################
```

**bblayers.conf**

```
# POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

OEROOT := "/home/ubuntu/yocto/sources/poky"
# add BSPDIR variable, as it is needed by recipes of NXP
BSPDIR := "${OEROOT}/../.."

#######################################
# IMPORTANT NOTE: change to correct location and username on your build!
MYBSPDIR := "/home/ubuntu/yocto/sources"
########################################

# In our BSPs active layers are defined by the manifest.xml for all BSPs. The
# bblayers.conf gets created by the init_bblayers.py script.
BBLAYERS ?= ""
BBLAYERS += "\
  ${OEROOT}/../poky/meta \
  ${OEROOT}/../poky/meta-poky \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-openembedded/meta-filesystems \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-openembedded/meta-perl \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-openembedded/meta-gnome \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-imx/meta-bsp \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-imx/meta-sdk \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-imx/meta-ml \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-browser/meta-chromium \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-clang \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-freescale \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-freescale-3rdparty \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-freescale-distro \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-nxp-demo-experience \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-python2 \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-qt5 \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-virtualization \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-rauc \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-phytec \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-ampliphy \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-security \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-security/meta-tpm \
  "
###################################
# Addition of the meta-java layer
BBLAYERS += "${MYBSPDIR}/meta-java"
###################################
```

We also tried creating and adding a Custom Layer containing openjdk-17 but that failed in the cross-compiling process started via `bitbake <recipe-name>` within the `do_configure()` part.

Is there any existing layer that we can add using a newer Java version than version 8 or are there any tips on how to get a Custom Layer running?

Comment: What errors do you get in the do_configure()?

Comment: Maybe building an SDK for cross compiling helps at debugging. Cross compiling openjdk using the sdk is probably not worth it, because lots of dependencies. See: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/sdk-manual/using.html

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue but i have solved it by creating [my own layer](https://github.com/lucimber/meta-openjdk-temurin) that leverages from the [Adoptium](https://adoptium.net) and [Eclipse Temurin](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/adoptium.temurin) projects.
It takes a prebuilt JRE and includes it in your OE/Yocto build. Btw, that is way faster than building the whole JRE on your own.

You can use my layer by adding it to your `bblayers.conf` and then append `openjdk-17-jre` to your `IMAGE_INSTALL` in your `local.conf` file. My layer currently supports JREs for ARM, ARM64 and x86_64 architecture.

Make sure your setup is using at least the `dunfell` codename/branch of OE/Yocto. You can have a look at the documentation of the [Yocto project on how to migrate](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/migration-guides/).

For everyone wondering why the official java layer `meta-java` seems to be stuck on version 8 of OpenJDK: Building and maintaining a JVM is much work. Furthermore in order to compile the desired version of a JVM, you need a bootstraping JVM of the previous version. E.g. by building OpenJDK 11 JRE you need OpenJDK 10 JDK. As i said, it is a lot of work.